# Collapsing Verts without creating triangles

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have modeled this fork and have no idea how to finish this end.

[image]
[image]

I would love to have the curvature just continue without ending where all the verts are.

If I collapse the verts, I create lots of triangles and this causes further problems especially with modifiers.

Maybe somebody has an idea.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

You could simply add some perpendicular edges.
That will keep the geometry even along the whole edge.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jachym. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Jachym. Thanks a lot. I have added 2 more pictures to my original post. I have no idea if that was what you meant or if I have done it the most eficient way (probably not).  It does not look exactly like what you have on your picture but it looks definitely much better now.

Comment: Hey :). You got the principle right, glad it works for you. Good luck with your project :).

Comment: Thanks Jachym. Guess there is still a long way to go;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you model your fork in the flat, and (initially) use a Solidify modifier to thicken it, there are no vertices to collapse. You can leave them as they are:

[image]

The longitudinal loops from the tines have been kept regular across the width by using the shipped add-on  *Loop Tools, > Space*

(All working under a *Mirror*) With *Curve*, *Solidify*, and *Subdiv*:

[image]

The Solidify can give you variable thickness by aiming it at a vertex group. You can paint the thicknesses in. If you need a bulbous end to the fork handle, I *think* you have to apply the *Solidify*, to put in a central loop:

[image]

... maybe, if you solidified before curving, you could do that non-destructively as well, with a *Bevel*?.. I haven't tried that. Anyway, you can proportionately <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> scale that loop along its normals, to make the profile rounder in some places, squarer in others.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks guys!