# Modeling a frypan: problems with sharp edges and overall wonky shape

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like some feedback on a model of the frypan I’ve made recently.

[image]

[Here's my Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vMntfur7gVTC6W8l-21RpabOk-W10JUY/view?usp=sharing)

I think I have a serious problem with the tip of the handle. It looks wonky, and the edges that form it are too sharp (I’ve added some examples below). Adding some geometry manually doesn’t make much of a difference at the current moment.

[image]

[image]

When modeling the handle, I took the next approach: 1) I extruded the mesh according to the reference. 2) Then, to make the widest part of the handle, I used the proportional editing on the bottom vertices. 3) After that I added some loopcuts to the side of the handle and edited mesh manually to match rhe reference. Now I’m not sure If I did something wrong or if it was the wrong approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @moonboots is bang on.. but the example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223060/35559) may contain further suggestions for varying thickness along the handle length, and rounding out the bulbous end smoothly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the top view to model the hole, then extrude to model the outter profile:

[image]

Extrude down:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* and move the vertices so that it continues to fit with the profile, bevel where you want to sharpen the edges:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I would be grateful if you could clarify a couple of points. 1) I was having those problems with sharp edges due to edge flow not matching the overall rounded shape of this object? 2) Why do you suggest using bevels? Why can't crease be used, for example?

Comment: hello, I'm not sure about your first question, could you please elaborate? For the second I personally prefer not to use crease edges, I prefer to learn how to do real proper topology, also have good control on the topology, and you can export your object if necessary, but some people will have a different opinion

Comment: hello! I was just trying to analyze why my topology of the tip of the handle is bad. As one of the reasons, direction the faces are going isn't right. As a consequence, I haven't got much control on my topology. It can also cause some shading problems. Now I'm wondering if my guess is correct.

Comment: maybe this answer will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228430/can-i-simplify-my-topology-in-that-way/228432#228432