# Distortions/Inconsistent lighting in model

Tags: modeling, lighting

I have modelled a fork and applied a metallic texture to it. However, the lighting seems to be inconsistent:
[image]

The entire fork is one object which I have joined together after modelling smaller pieces first:
[image]

And here's how the geometry is done:
[image]

What are some common causes for this problem occuring?

Here is the blender file:
[image]

Comment: Hello, it's due to smooth shading and bad topology, maybe share your object so that we can propose a solution?

Comment: Blender file has been added. I've changed it a little bit since and have gotten slight improvements, though there are still a few distortions. Thanks for taking a look. I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Another example, (very similar to mooboots, actually,) of modelling a fork :https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223060/35559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology is not very good, and it's always harder to fix a topology that is a bit dense. I would personally redo it from scratch with a topology that is as simple as possible, like that:

[image]

Here is what it gives with a stack of modifier, *Curve, Solidify, Bevel* and *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, mate! I'm going to give this a shot.